# Integrating all the social sites using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a website using ASP.Net and I want to integrate Social Network that gives the user to share a page to their Facebook, twitter,Google plus, linked in and other accounts

Comment: I hope it goes well for you :) Do you have a specific question to ask?

Answer (score 2):

These sites will use OAuth, which you will need to integrate into your site.

For example, you could create a Facebook Application using the developers section on Facebook and then use the [c# Facebook API](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) from your ASP.Net application to authenticate with the application and post content to the users timeline. I implemented something like this recently, it's pretty simple to do.

You won't have a 'universal set of credentials' for all of the social media that you have mentioned, so you would need to manage and perform OAuth for each of the different Media, e.g. As well as post to Facebook, create a tweet for the user as well.

It's certainly possible, there are Social Marketing applications that do something like this, you just need to manage the access to the OAuth partners.

Just remember, *never* store credentials that the user has entered in your site. They are not managed by your site so you should never attempt to store them or do anything with them, always delegate to the 3rd party site and receive your access token back. That's all your application should be interested in

Have a read up on how OAuth works. Also, visit each sites developer documentation to see how their specific implementation of OAuth works. There are c# client applications for accessing the sites (c# facebook api, c# twitter api etc etc)